# Is there any way to save local and global descriptors as txt instead of pcd in Point Cloud Library?

Tags: point-cloud-library, pcl

I have used [this script](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/7d52b107223ef8adec990608e8685392b48d79c6/doc/tutorials/content/sources/iccv2011/src/test_feature_estimation.cpp#L105) to generate local and global descriptors from a point cloud. The script lets you save the descriptors in PCD format (line 105 of the script) but I'm having trouble loading the pcd files in Python to train a model [Opened a discussion [here]](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/discussions/5338).
I'm thinking of an alternative. Does anyone know a way to save the descriptors as a txt file instead of pcd? Thanks!

Comment: You can try saving it as an ASCII PCD file and perhaps delete the header

Comment: @IBitMyBytes Thanks for the reply. I just saved it in default PCD format in PCL and then read it like a text file in Python and removed the headers.

Answer (score 0):

@IBitMyBytes Thanks for the reply. I just saved it in default PCD format in PCL and then read it like a text file in Python and removed the headers.